# How to send validation error massage? Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I want to display validation error msg on registration form. Msg should be displayed when Login already exist in database.

MY error: Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Login_r.(rule)
Pleas try to help me, its very important. Thank you

config/form_validation.php

```
$config = array(
    'login' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'login',
            'label' => 'Login',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
    ),
    'register' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'name_r',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'required|alpha'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'lastname_r',
            'label' => 'Lastname',
            'rules' => 'required|alpha'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'login_r',
            'label' => 'Login_r',
            'rules' => 'required|callback_rule'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'password_r',
            'label' => 'Password_r',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'confirm_password_r',
            'label' => 'Confirm_password',
            'rules' => 'required|matches[password_r]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'email_r',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'adres_r',
            'label' => 'Adres',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
    ),                          
);
```

Controller:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('register') == false)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Dzialaj !');
    $this->load->view('content/register');
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('content/index');
    $name_r  = $this->input->post('name_r');
    $lastname_r = $this->input->post('lastname_r');
    $login_r = $this->input->post('login_r');
    $password_r  = $this->input->post('password_r');            
    $email_r  = $this->input->post('email_r'); 
    $adres_r = $this->input->post('adres_r');

    $data_db = array(
        'name' => $name_r,
        'lastname' => $lastname_r,
        'login' => $login_r,
        'password' => $password_r,
        'email' => $email_r,
        'adres' => $adres_r
        );
    $this->Main_model->register($data_db);
}
```

Model:

```
public function register($data_db) {

    $this->db->where('login',$data_db['login']);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $row = $query->row();

    if($row->login){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');
    } else {
        $this->db->insert('users', $data_db);
    }
```

View(forms)

```
    <?php
echo validation_errors();
echo form_open();
echo 'Imie: ' . form_input('name_r');
echo br(2);
echo 'Nazwisko: ' . form_input('lastname_r');
echo br(2);
echo 'Login: ' . form_input('login_r');
echo br(2);
echo 'Haslo: ' . form_password('password_r');
echo br(2);
echo 'Potwierdz Haslo: ' . form_password('confirm_password_r');
echo br(2);
echo 'E-mail: ' . form_input('email_r');
echo br(2);
echo 'Adres: ' . form_input('adres_r');
echo br(1);
echo form_submit('zarejestrowany','Stworz konto');

echo form_close();
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your validation of Login_r specifies the use of a callback called 'rule', but there aren't any callbacks at all listed in your code. Do you have a callback for this validation created anywhere?

Comment: Oh yeah. becouse I was trying to run this on Model, Controller and view, but in every place that doesn't work.

Comment: Oh wait, there is a call back at third line in Controller

Comment: No... a callback is going to be a separate function in your controller. I didn't understand your first comment, but there is no callback posted here. CI Manual: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=validation#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: I don't understand. My validation rules are in the another file config/form_validation.php  and there is a callback. 'rules' => 'required|callback_rule'    hmm....

Comment: That's not a callback. You're setting a rule that says Login_r has to satisfy the rule you created (the callback) which has a name 'rule'. Somewhere in your controller there needs to be a function named `rule()` where you define what it is you want to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136772/discussion-between-pacio-and-adi212).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you have your validation code you posted, that should be in the controller too. I'd suggest refactoring so you don't do any validation in the model:

Model:

```
public function get_user($login) {
    $this->db->where('login',$login);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row;
}

public function register($data_db) {
    $this->db->insert('users', $data_db);
}
```

Controller:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('register') == false)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Dzialaj !');
    $this->load->view('content/register');
}
else
{
$this->load->view('content/index');
$name_r  = $this->input->post('name_r');
$lastname_r = $this->input->post('lastname_r');
$login_r = $this->input->post('login_r');
$password_r  = $this->input->post('password_r');            
$email_r  = $this->input->post('email_r'); 
$adres_r = $this->input->post('adres_r');

$user = $this->Main_model->get_user();
if($user->login) {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');
    redirect('content/register')
}
 $data_db = array(
    'name' => $name_r,
    'lastname' => $lastname_r,
    'login' => $login_r,
    'password' => $password_r,
    'email' => $email_r,
    'adres' => $adres_r
              );
$this->Main_model->register($data_db);
```

This still isn't great since I have to use a redirect if it $user->login is true, it would be even better to create the callback like I mentioned in the chat, but I don't really understand how your code is structured.

Comment: Same thing like before. How should I name callback ?

Comment: Sorry, in my example you were supposed to not use the callback, but I I was about to log off for the day. 

Post your entire controller so I have a better idea of what you're doing and I'll update my answer so you use the callback correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs a function called "rule" (because you have a rule called "callback_rule" in your form_validation rules).

```
function rule($form_value)
{
  if(<condition for form value is good>)
  {
    return TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('login_r','your error message');
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```